# Problema con java

Tags: java

Me está pasando algo muy raro. Estoy haciendo un programa, hago cambios, guardo y demás, hasta ahí todo bien. A la hora de ejecutar el programa no se me actualiza. Por ejemplo, he hecho dos metodos, uno de ello validación:

```
 public static int pedirPotencia() {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int potencia=0;

        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Introduce la potencia(CV) del coche");
                potencia = teclado.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error");
            }
        } while (validarPotencia(potencia) == false);

        return potencia;

    }

    public static boolean validarPotencia(int potencia) {
        boolean validarPotencia;

        if (potencia >= 60 && potencia <= 1200) {

            validarPotencia = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("La potencia del coche no está entre 60 y 1200, por favor, vuelve a introducir una potencia correcta");
            validarPotencia = false;
        }
        return validarPotencia;
    }
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa a la hora de meter la potencia me sale como si hubiese metido un numero inferior a 60 o mayor a 1200. Y para colmo me sale este mensaje que es el anterior a lo que guarde posteriormente cuando introduzco la potencia. Fijaos que no es el mismo mensaje que tengo en los metodos:

***Introduce los CV del coche
90
La potencia del coche está entre 60 y 1200, por favor, vuelve a introducir una potencia correcta
Introduce los CV del coche***

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de estar ejecutando ese código? Si te salen mensajes anteriores o bien no estás ejecutando el mismo código o no has compilado tras los cambios

Comment: Por que no iba a estar ejecutando el mismo código si no lo tengo duplicado?

Comment: Nosotros no sabemos si lo tienes duplicado o no. Te lo comento porque es una posibilidad (que a todos los ha pasado alguna vez). ¿Has compilado los cambios?

Comment: Si si le he dado a compilar, lo he guardado, lo he limpiado, y nada....

Comment: ¿Qué IDE estás usando?¿Eclipse?

Comment: Prueba copiar el código, borrar la clase, crear una clase nueva y pegas de nuevo el código. Y si sigue dando problemas, prueba a cambiar de IDE aunque sea solo para comprobar

Comment: Lo he solucionado, estaba fallando en una validación anterior a este paso, el cual a la hora de elegir coche o moto, se bugeaba.